# Average Frequency of 1's in an Infinite Binary Sequences Can be Anything Between 0 and 1

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

The following question came up when me and a friend of mine were discussing some basic things about probability:

Let $p$ be a real number in $[0,1]$.

Does there exist a sequence $(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots)$ with each $x_i$ being either $0$ or $1$, such that

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{n} =p
$$

where $f(n)= x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n$, that is, $f(n)$ is the number of times $1$ has appeared in the first $n$ slots.

**Motivation:** Consider a coin which may or may not be fair, and say the probability of "heads" showing up is $p$.
Suppose we want to have a machine which simulates this coin.
That is, we want to have a machine which shows either "H" or "T" every second ('second' here is a unit of time) on its screen.
If the machine properly simulates the coin, then we must have the average frequency of "H" occuring is $p$.

Comment: Well, if $p$ is a rational number, then there certainly exists a sequence that can produce this because it can be produced in a finite number of steps and thus that can simply be repeated over and over again.  I'm not so sure if $p$ is irrational.  I would think that since an irrational number can be estimated with arbitrary precision by a rational number, that, using the definition of a limit, you _could_ create an irrational number as well (although the period would, itself be infinite).

Comment: Yes. For rationals it is easy. For irrationals I am stumped. One possible line of though is that given any irrational number, there is an increasing sequence of rationals which converge to the irrational. This din't help me much because I wasn't able to control the size of the denominators.

Comment: Can't you state that you can create a rational number $p \pm \epsilon$ in some $n_1$ finite steps and then it becomes a matter of producing the irrational value of $\epsilon$ in the next $n_2$ steps (with appropriately reproducing the initial $n_1$ sequence).  Then, it seems to me that you can show that you can have $\epsilon$ approach $0$ as you take more and more steps.

Comment: I am not sure how this could work. If you are able to beat down the details then please post it as an answer.

Comment: You're asking two very different things here... the main question asks for a sequence with the given property, but your motivation shows that you actually want independent and identically distributed realizations of a random variable. All answers posted so far don't satisfy this motivation, they don't produce random or independent sequence entries. The way to achieve what your motivation states is simply to draw samples from a [Bernoulli distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution).

Comment: It is unfortunate that the notation in the question suppresses the dependency of the function $f$ on the sequence $x=(x_1,x_2\ldots)$. I see that several answers (including the currently accepted one) define that sequence $x$ in terms of$~f$, which in principle gives a circular definition.  Those answers actually lead to a proper _recursive_ (or inductive, I forget) definition of their sequence, but the recursion is not explicit nor even mentioned.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I am only interested in the existence of such a sequence. Though it is interesting to have some kind of characterization of all the sequences which fulfill the requirement of the question.

Comment: @caffeinemachine: That was more or less my point. A circular definition does not establish existence (or anything, for that matter). But a proper recursive definition does.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Start with $x_1=0$ and then just let $x_{n+1}=1$ whenever $f(n)/n\leq p$ and $x_{n+1}=0$ whenever $f(n)/n> p$.

It's easy to prove by induction that we will always have $\left|\frac{f(n)}n-p\right|\leq\frac 1n$ and so $f(n)/n\rightarrow p$.

Comment: I was just about to post the same thing. No need for complicated formulas.

Comment: I thought of a stupid joke proof: Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be i.i.d. $\mathop{Bernoulli}(p)$. Then by the law of large numbers $ \lim(X_1+\dots+X_n)/n=p$ with probability one. Sets with measure $1$ are non-empty.

Answer (score 5):

This is always possible. The idea is that we'll build the sequence $x_k$ so that $f(d)/d$ is always the best rational approximation to $p$ with denominator $d$.

Note that, for any irrational number $p$ and fixed denominator $d$, there is a unique best rational approximation to $p$ with denominator $d$, namely the unique $n/d$ satisfying the inequality
$$
\left|p-\frac{n}{d}\right|<\frac{1}{2d}
$$
(because the fractions with denominator $d$ are equally spaced at a distance of $\frac{1}{d}$, and so every real number except rationals with denominator $2d$ is within $\frac{1}{2d}$ of exactly one of them.)

That inequality can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{2n-1}{2d} < p < \frac{2n+1}{2d}
$$
which implies that
$$
\frac{2n-1}{2(d+1)} < p < \frac{2(n+1)+1}{2(d+1)}
$$
(as $\frac{2n-1}{2(d+1)}=\frac{2n-1}{2d+2} < \frac{2n-1}{2d}$, $\frac{2n+1}{2d} \leq \frac{2n+3}{2d+2}=\frac{2(n+1)+1}{2(d+1)}$ for all positive integers $n$ and $d$ with $n \leq d$).

This in turn implies that either
$$
\left|p-\frac{n}{d+1}\right| < \frac{1}{2(d+1)}
$$
or
$$
\left|p-\frac{n+1}{d+1}\right| < \frac{1}{2(d+1)}
$$
which is to say that, if $n/d$ is the best rational approximation to $p$ with denominator $d$, then either $n/(d+1)$ or $(n+1)/(d+1)$ is the best rational approximation to $p$ with denominator $d+1$. Assuming inductively that we've already chosen $x_1,\dots,x_d$ so that $f(d)=n$, we then take $x_{d+1}$ to be $0$ if $p$ is well-approximated by $n/(d+1)$, or $1$ if $p$ is well-approximated by $(n+1)/(d+1)$. It follows that 
$$\left|\frac{f(d)}{d}-p\right| < \frac{1}{2d}$$
for all $d$, and so in particular $\lim_{d \to \infty} \frac{f(d)}{d}=p$.

Note that this procedure actually works for rational numbers as well — and produces the sort of repeating sequence you'd expect — except that you have to make some specific rule for when $n/(d+1)$ and $(n+1)/(d+1)$ are equally good approximations to $p$. It doesn't matter what rule you choose, though...

Comment: Great answer! Please forgive me if I don't end up accepting yours. I may accept barok manos's answer because it is more basic.

Answer (score 3):

Let
$$x_i=1\iff((i-1)p,\ ip]\cap\mathbb N\ne\emptyset,$$
otherwise $x_i=0.$ Observe that
$$\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}n=\frac{\lfloor np\rfloor}n,$$
$$p-\frac1n=\frac{np-1}n\lt\frac{\lfloor np\rfloor}n\le\frac{np}n=p,$$
whence
$$p-\frac1n\lt\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}n\le p.$$

Comment: Brilliant. I like this better than my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct $x_n$ that will satisfy this requirement by definition:

- If $p=0$, then $\forall{i}:x_i=0$
- If $p=1$, then $\forall{i}:x_i=1$
- If $0<p<1$, then:

  $x_1=\lfloor2p\rfloor$

  $
     \forall{i>1}:x_i=
      \begin{cases}
       0 & \Big|{\frac{f(i-1)}{i}-p}\Big|\leq\Big|{\frac{f(i-1)+1}{i}-p}\Big|\\
       1 & \Big|{\frac{f(i-1)}{i}-p}\Big|  > \Big|{\frac{f(i-1)+1}{i}-p}\Big|\\
      \end{cases}
    $

Answer (score 2):

Let $p \in [0,1]$.

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define $s_n = \max \{ \frac{k}{n} : k \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and } \frac{k}{n} \leq p\}$. Also define $s_0=0$. Note that $s_n$ converges to $p$ because $0 \leq p-s_n < \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$.

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define $x_n := ns_n - (n-1)s_{n-1}$. Note that $\frac{f(n)}{n} =\frac{ns_n}{n}= s_n$, which converges to $p$.

Thus, we'll be finished if we can prove that $x_n \in \{ 0, 1 \}$, i.e, if we can prove that $(n-1)s_{n-1} \leq ns_n \leq 1+(n-1)s_{n-1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. To prove this, let $n \geq 2$. Note that if $k <n$ and $\frac{k}{n-1} \geq p$, then $\frac{k+1}{n}\geq\frac{k}{n-1} \geq p$, so by applying this to $k=(n-1)s_{n-1}+1$ we get that $ns_n \leq 1+(n-1)s_{n-1}$. On the other hand we know that if $\frac{k}{n-1}<p$, then $\frac{k}{n} < \frac{k}{n-1}<p$, so applying this to $k= (n-1)s_{n-1}$ we get that $ns_n \geq (n-1)s_{n-1}$.

**Edit:** As an example of this construction, consider the case where $p=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Then for the sequence of $s_n$ we get $0, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{5}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{4}{7}, \frac{5}{8}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{7}{10},\frac{7}{11}, \frac{2}{3} ...$ Then for $ns_n$ we get $0,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,8...$. Thus for the $x_n$ we get $0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1...$