# For any given value x, are there uncountably many (countably infinite) binary sequences (ones and zeroes) whose limiting relative frequency is x

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, number-theory, measure-theory, probability-theory

I have the following question, and given few proofs (provided by friends, professors, and my myself) which seem to work, I suspect the answer is yes: But I am still not completely sure. The question is:

(A): "For any given value x, are there uncountably many (countably infinite) binary sequences (ones and zeroes) whose limiting relative frequency is x"

Is this an open question? I ask this because all of those whom I've asked, had either not thought about the question nor knew the answer until they came up with their own proof. So has (A) been proven in the literature, and if so where?

I am interested because if the answer to (A) is no, it can be easily shown that the Kolmogorov formalization/calculus of probability is undermined. This holds because the Kolmogorov calculus seems to require that (A) is true. That the Kolmogorov calculus requires (A) can be easily shown given its axiom of countable additivity, and its theorem: the strong law of large numbers (ie, simply consider that any infinite sequence of independent and identical random variables/trails has probability zero, if the individual outcome probabilities on each trial is less than one).

Even if non-standard analysis is applied (so that infinite sequences composed of individual independent and identical random variable with non zero probability are assigned infinitesimal probability values, rather then zero probability values), it appears that this result (ie (A)) is demanded by the Kolmogorov calculus

Comment: Of course there are uncountably many (in fact continuum many) sequences whose limiting relative frequency is $x$. Let $M$ be some fixed infinite subset of $\mathbb N$ with density zero, e.g., the set of all perfect squares. Now, given one infinite binary sequence $s$ with limiting relative frequency $x$, we can get other sequences with the same limiting relative frequency by flipping the terms of $s$ corresponding to an arbitrary subset of $M$. Inasmuch as there are continuum many subsets of $M$, we get continuum many different sequences this way.

Comment: Of course this is not an open question, and never was. Sorry I can't give you a reference

Comment: Yes, some of the possible proofs ive seen use that logic; although one must be careful with uniqueness and ordering; Suppose, for example each term in s, si,  corresponds to a term in M, mi; if we then consider some infinite subset of M, lets call it P for example,  and re-arrange the terms in s, si with regard to which mi are present in P, then the sequence, S, produced from this re-arrangement may not longer have limiting relative frequency x. This may not be an issue  so long as one only uses P's which are finite subsets of M (but then two distinct finite subsets P, might produce the same S

Comment: I thought we were talking about **binary** sequences. So $s_i\in\{0,1\}$ for each $i\in\mathbb N.$ Given a set $P\subseteq M$ the new sequence $s^P$ is defined so that $s^P_i=s_i$ if $i\notin P$ and $s^P_i=1-s_i$ if $i\in P.$ I don't know what "rearrangement" you are referring to.

Comment: yes (A) appears to be true; the first premise required which that for any value x in [0,1] there is a binary sequence with relative frequency x seems to have been answered in  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209758/average-frequency-of-1s-in-an-infinite-binary-sequences-can-be-anything-between?rq=1